# How could JPA annotation be used to represent DateTime(3) as datatype in MySQL column in the database

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So I would like to have an entity date column to represent the datatype of mysql column as `datetime(3)` in the database. 
By default, if the column is `Date`, it is represented as `datetime` in mysql but I would like `datetime(3)`. Reason being that, this could effectively represent a precision like `yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss.SSS` unlike the default which is `yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@Column(columnDefinition = "DATETIME (3)")` should do the job if your MySQL version support fractional-second time datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify data type of columns as below:

MODIFY COLUMN `XXXX` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000';